# Towers of Hanoi understanding

Tags: recursion, towers-of-hanoi

I have seen this code on stack overflow post. I didn't understand what is the  function of this line **int Other = 3 - Startpeg - Endpeg;** Can anyone explain

```
//Pegs are counted 0 to 2

void Tower(int Disk, int Startpeg, int Endpeg)
{
    if(Disc <= 0)  //Sanity check
        return;

    if(Disc == 1)
        cout << "Move disk from "<<Startpeg<<" to "<<Endpeg<<endl;
    else
    {
        int Other = 3 - Startpeg - Endpeg;
        Tower(Disc-1, Startpeg,  Other);
        Tower(1, Startpeg, Endpeg); //Inline output would do here... Calling for message consistency.
        Tower(Disc-1, Other, Endpeg);
    }
}
```

Can anyone explain this line `int Other = 3 - Startpeg - Endpeg;` what is doing here and explain this line of code, what's going on here, Is it subtracting the endpeg from start and then then whole from 3 ?

Comment: `Other` gives the index of the tower which is *neither* `Startpeg` *nor* `Endpeg`. E.g. for `Startpeg = 2`, `Endpeg = 0`, the only other peg is at index `1`, which is indeed the value of `Other`.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps **Otherpeg** or **Thirdpeg** would clarify a little.  As meowgoesthedog already showed in an example, this is a way of finding the third peg, the one other than the start or end peg.

The algebra behind this is simple: if we have three pegs with *any* numbering -- use **a, b, c** here -- then the sum of all three is `a + b + c`.  If we know two of the peg values, we can get the third by subtracting from that sum.
  For instance,

```
total = a + b + c
// if we already know a and c, find the other peg value ...
other = total - a - c
```

More simply, this gives us `other = b`.

In the specific case, we've numbered the pegs 0, 1, 2 -- the **total** is 3, which is hard-coded into the program.

Does that beat the topic to death?  :-)